# How to move array object to first index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How to bring array object to first Index

```
   struct ScheduleDateTime {
     var startDate: String?
     var endDate: String?
     var isScheduled: Bool?
    }

var scheduleDateTime = [ScheduleDateTime]()
    func reArrange(){
        if let scheduleList = scheduleDateTime{
          if  scheduleList.count > 1 {
              for each in scheduleList {
                  if each.isScheduled == true {
                    // Bring the item to first Index.

                  }
              }
            } 
        }
    }
```

How to bring the array Index to first position based on above `isSchedule == true` condition

Comment: for 0..<scheduleDateTime.count {
 let oldSchedule = scheduleDateTime[0]
 let isScheduled = oldSchedule.isScheduled
 if isScheduled {
  scheduleDateTime.removeAtIndex(i)
  let newSchedule = ScheduleDateTime(startDate: oldSchedule.startDate, oldSchedule.endDate, true)
  scheduleDateTime.insert(newSchedule, at: 0)
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `sort` based on comparing `isScheduled`. This will move all `isScheduled == true` items to the front of the array.

```
let input : [ScheduleDateTime] = 
  [.init(startDate: "Item1", endDate: nil, isScheduled: false),
   .init(startDate: "Item2", endDate: nil, isScheduled: false),
   .init(startDate: "Item3", endDate: nil, isScheduled: true),
   .init(startDate: "Item4", endDate: nil, isScheduled: false),
   .init(startDate: "Item5", endDate: nil, isScheduled: true)]

let output = input.sorted(by: { $0.isScheduled == true && $1.isScheduled != true })

print(output.map(\.startDate!))
```

Yields:

> ["Item3", "Item5", "Item1", "Item2", "Item4"]